# Modify number with pattern X.XXX

Tags: sed

I have variable data with digits and minus "[-]", "[0-9]". It's may be:

```
source NUMBER  ->result NUMBER AFTER MODIFY  
XXX ->0.XXX,
XXXX ->X.XXX,
XXXXX ->XX.XXX,
-XXX -> -0.XXX,
-XXXX ->-X.XXX,
-XXXXX ->-XX.XXX,
```

Can this be done with sed?

Comment: it looks like you want to print a leading dot for decimals, etc. If you post proper input we may come with a `printf` way to do it.

Comment: Post some actual sample input and associated output. Something a script could be tested against.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say:

```
sed -r 's/[0-9]{3}$/.&/; s/^(-?)\./\10./' filename
```

That is:

```
s/[0-9]{3}$/.&/    # put a dot before the last three digits in a line
s/^(-?)\./\10./    # if the result of this begins with . or -., insert a 0
                   # before the .
```

`-r` requires GNU sed. If you're on BSD or Mac OS X, which comes with BSD sed, you could use

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{3\}$/.&/;s/^\(-\?\)\./\10./' filename
```

That's the same thing with basic instead of extended regex syntax.

**Addendum:** Come to think of it, this appears to be equivalent to

```
awk '{ printf("%.3f\n", $0 / 1000) }' filename
```

Comment: `awk '{printf(.../1000)...'` Cool! +1

Comment: plus 1 for the awk answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\(-*\)\(.*\)\(...\)/\10\2.\3/;s/0\([1-9]\)/\1/' YourFile
```

another way, remove 0 if needed and without back reference

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/(\d{3})\b/.$1/;          
          s/\B\./0./'   file
```

- line1 :  `222<word-boundary>  --> .222`
- line2 : `<non-word-boundary>.222 --> 0.222`